# Google Calendar Attendee Groups added by API are different than groups added by UI

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-groups

Whenever I add a Google group to a calendar event in the web UI I get an option to expand the group, and sends individual invitations to the group members. But when I add a group to a calendar event via the API (as an `attendees[].email` ) it does NOT send individual invitations and does not allow expanding the group. I also cannot later add the group via the web UI to get the individual emails without first deleting the group from the invite, then re-adding them.

How can I get events created from the API to match an event created from the UI when a Google group is among the attendees?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use the [Calendar Get Event API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) from both the created events and the existing event of the Google Group. Then compare the eventId of the created event to the existing event from the Google Group to match the created event to the existing event.

Comment: I'm missing a connection here. When I create an event via the API I do not get "expansion" of the google group email, instead get a single attendee of the group and it is not recognized as a group. When a different and unrelated event is created through the web UI it recognizes the google group email as a group instead of an individual. I'm trying to figure out how to get the API to recognize the google group email address as a group instead of an individual.